# Search Algorithm - Buckets and Stones

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi I'm searching an algorithm to solve the following problem:

There are n buckets and y Stones, that can be thrown into the buckets. After every student throws stones x-times in random buckets, the buckets have a different stone count. Now the professor takes 100 Post-Its and randomly put these postits on the buckets. He says: "Every Post-Id signals one percent of the amount of stones in all buckets, so if Bucket A has 10 Post-Its, it can have in the end 10 stones if Y=100 (amount of overall stones). Please change the amount of stones in the buckets, so every bucket has the maximum of stone in it.The team with the smallest transfer amounts (see TransferAction.class below) wins the beer!"

This should be a common distributon problem, but I have no idea how to solve it. I have to find a algo with the minimum change actions, so I take some summary statistics to find out the best algo over some runs/tryouts/time.

Can anyone help or point me to the best algo?

***There are some restrictions***: So it is not possible to put all stone in one single bucket and then put the right amount back! The minimum means, that Bucket A can put some stone in Bucket B, but then bucket B can not put any stone is bucket A any more.

Here is my Code so far:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.SummaryStatistics;

public class Main {
    private static final float Take_Over__Percent_Maximum = 100;

    private static Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> averageSizeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int runs = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < runs ; i++) {
            List<TransferAction> transferActions = doSingleRun();
            averageSizeList.add( transferActions.size());
            System.out.println("The size of transfers:" + transferActions.size());
        }

        calculateAverage(averageSizeList);

    }

    private static void calculateAverage(List<Integer> averageSizeList) {

        System.out.println();
        double[] observed = averageSizeList.stream().mapToDouble(i->i).toArray();
        SummaryStatistics sampleStats = new SummaryStatistics();

        for (int i = 0; i < observed.length; i++) {
            sampleStats.addValue(observed[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(sampleStats.toString());

    }

    private static List<TransferAction> doSingleRun() {
        // create some buckets
        List<Bucket> bucketList = new ArrayList<Bucket>();
        int numberOfBuckets = 5;
        float percentageOfAllStonesInBucket = Take_Over__Percent_Maximum
                / numberOfBuckets;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBuckets; i++) {
            Bucket bucket = new Bucket(percentageOfAllStonesInBucket);
            bucketList.add(bucket);
        }

        // now fill buckets with stones
        int fillActions = 100;
        List<FillAction> fillActionsList = new ArrayList<FillAction>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fillActions; i++) {
            UUID randomBucketId = bucketList.get(
                    RANDOM.nextInt(bucketList.size())).getId();
            BigDecimal randomAmount = new BigDecimal(RANDOM.nextLong());
            FillAction fillAction = new FillAction(randomAmount, randomBucketId);
            fillActionsList.add(fillAction);
        }

        // now try to change the amount of stones in the buckets, so in the end
        // every bucket has the right percent of all stones in it
        return calculate(bucketList,fillActionsList);

    }

    private static List<TransferAction> calculate(List<Bucket> bucketList,
            List<FillAction> fillActionsList) {     
        List<TransferAction> transferActions = new ArrayList<TransferAction>();

        // the magic should be done here
        //...
        //...


        //now every bucket has maximum percent of all stone or equal stones
        return transferActions;
    }

}
```

The bucket Class :

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Bucket {

    private final UUID id;
    private float percentTakeOver;

    public Bucket(float percentTakeOver) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        if (percentTakeOver > 100) {
            this.percentTakeOver = 100;
        } else if (percentTakeOver < 0) {
            this.percentTakeOver = 0;
        } else {
            this.percentTakeOver = percentTakeOver;
        }
    }

    public float getPercentTakeOver() {
        return percentTakeOver;
    }

    public void setPercentTakeOver(float percentTakeOver) {
        this.percentTakeOver = percentTakeOver;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The FillAction class FillAction class (best algo has not many FillActions):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.UUID;

public class FillAction {

    private final BigDecimal amount;
    private final UUID bucketID;

    public FillAction(BigDecimal amount, UUID bucketID) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.bucketID = bucketID;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public UUID getBucketID() {
        return bucketID;
    }

}
```

Next:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TransferAction {

    private final UUID fromBucket;
    private final UUID toBucket;
    private final BigDecimal amount;

    public TransferAction(UUID fromBucket, UUID toBucket, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.fromBucket = fromBucket;
        this.toBucket = toBucket;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public UUID getFromBucket() {
        return fromBucket;
    }

    public UUID getToBucket() {
        return toBucket;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed you can produce every percentage? What if *y* is *17* (prime number)?

Comment: Yes why not. You have 3 Bucket (=x) and 17 Stones (=y). Perhaps Bucket A gets 3 Stones, B 7 Stones and C also 7 Stones.

Comment: Can you clarify this: "Please change the amount of stones in the buckets, so every bucket has the **maximum of stone** in it. The team with the **least change rate**"? Specifically the bolded parts. Also, how can the stones be moved? A group from any bucket to any bucket? And is that considered one move regardless of how many stones are moved and how far?

Comment: @aexerus: because you cannot fill a bucket with say 50% of the stones, no integral percentage can exactly be achieved...

Comment: 1.) If there exists 1000 stones and Bucket A have 10% possible, then A can have 100 stones in it.
2.) change rate means= minimum amount of stones transfered to another.
3.) Its possible to take just 1 Stone from A to B or you you transfer 100 stones from A to B. The distance does not matter!

Comment: @CommuSoft: Its ok to round the value, because y is a high number.

Comment: It's still really unclear.  When you say in your last comment that "A can have 100 stones in it", "can" doesn't make sense -- do you mean "at the end, A **must** have 100 stones in it?"  If so, then this contradicts your statement that it's "OK to round the values", since that would mean there are many allowed configurations (in this example, Bucket A would be allowed to wind up with anywhere from 95 to 104 stones).

Answer (score 1):

I does not know exyctly what you mean, but I will try to understand your requirements with an example of my understanding.

Available Stones= x15

Buckets= A + B + C

Capacity of Bucket A= 1/3 ~33,33% --> this means 15 * (1/3)= 5 Stones

Capacity of Bucket B= 1/3 ~33,33% --> this means 15 * (1/3)= 5 Stones

Capacity of Bucket C= 1/3 ~33,33% --> this means 15 * (1/3)= 5 Stones

Initial Stones (symbol 0) in Bucket:

```
 A=4  | B=8   | C=3
##### | ##### | ##### 
# 0 # | # 0 # | # 0 #
# 0 # | # 0 # | # 0 #
# 0 # | # 0 # | # 0 #
# 0 # | # 0 # | #   #
#   # | # 0 # | #   #
#   # | # 0 # | #   #
#   # | # 0 # | #   #
#   # | # 0 # | #   #
##### | ##### | #####
```

**I. The easy Way Algorithm**

Idea: Imagine a bucket ring.

Steps:
1.) Take first bucket, if capcacity is reached take all additional stones and put it to the next bucket. And go to next bucket.

2.) If second bucket capacity is reached, then put all additonal stones to next bucket. If capacity is not reached. Go to next bucket

....

Finished: Not easy to check, but if you iterate over all buckets and no bucket has capacity reached, then you are finished.

Example:

Step 1: 4 stones in A. Move 4 Stones to B. Now A have 0 stones and B has 12 stones.

```
   4
A  -> B
4  0 12
```

Step 2: A is empty. B has 12 Stones. Now move 7 stones from B to C. B now have 5 stones and C 10 stones.

```
   4    7
A  -> B -> C
4  0 12 5  10
```

Step 3: A is empty. B has 5 Stones and C 10 stones. Now move 5 stones from C to A. C now have 5 stones and A 5 stones and B still have 5 stones.

```
   4     7     5
A  -> B  -> C  -> A
4  0  12 5  10 5  5
```

Moved Stones=15

Transactions=3x the `->` sign

Hope you understand my way of symbolic calculations :-)

---

**II. A intelligent Algorithm**

Idea: You know what bucket reached capacity and what bucket has free capacity left.

Steps:

1.) Iterate over all buckets and remember buckets with reached capacity and the amount of additonal stones (List 1). Also remember the buckets with available capacity left in extra list (List 2) and the amount of free space.

2.) Iterate over List 1 and take first item from list 2. Then transfer all stones over capacity from Bucket A (from list 1) to B (from list 2,B perhaps reaches capacity!!!). Then delete Bucket 1 from A and Bucket 2 from B.

3.) Do so until one list does not have any items

4.) Got to step 1 and follow the steps 2-4. Finish this, if List 1 does not have any items left.

Example:

Step 1: List1={B=3} and List2={A=1,C=2}. If you take a look at the next algo then you know why i remeber the value 3 for additional stones in bucket A, and 1 missing stone in Bucket A or 2 missong stones in Bucket B!

Step 2: Take B from List1 and A from List2. Now move 3 stones like below. Delete B from List1 and A from List2. Now List1 is empty so start with Step 1.

```
   3
 B -> A
 8 5  7
```

Step 1 iteration 2: List1={A=2} and List2={C=2}. See B is not in any list!!!

Step 2 iteration 2: Take A from List1 and C from List2. Now move 2 stones like below. Delete A from List1 and C from List2. Now List1 is empty so start with Step 1.

```
   3    2
 B -> A -> C
 8 5  7 5  5
```

Step 1 iteration 3: List1={}and List2={}. See both lists are empty (but important is just list1), so we are finished!

Moved Stones=5

Transactions=2x the `->` sign

---

**III. A more intelligent Algorithm**

Idea: You know what bucket reached capacity and what bucket has free capacity left. But now we remeber the amount of additional or missing stones, but look below.

Example:

Step 1: List1={B=3} and List2={A=1,C=2}

Step 2:

```
   1
 B -> A
 8 5  5

   2
 B -> C
 8 5  5
```

Finished. All Buckets now have 5 stones!

Moved Stones=3

Transactions=2x the `->` sign

---

**This is the end of my post**

---

Perhaps there are beter Algorithms, but I does not know them by name and I dont want to write more explanations. But I hope I have give you some idea of possible implemenations.

Perhaps some other person can name some Algorithms by name!